# Do all Dhamma teachings aim us at release?

Tags: theravada, reference-request, pali-canon, mahayana, sutta-reference

I read the statement recently that all Dhamma teachings aim to produce disenchantment, for the purpose of release / unbinding.

Any thoughts on this subject are welcome, but my question is: **Which suttas talk about this?** And preferably, in a way that clearly supports the writer's claim.

Answer (score 3):

All of the Dhamma teachings result in reduction of suffering.

But not all of the Dhamma teachings result in complete liberation.

The right view with effluents ([MN 117](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.117.than.html)) is targeted at beginners (especially lay persons).

However, according to [SN 42.7](https://suttacentral.net/sn42.7/en/sujato), the Buddha taught the whole Dhamma to everyone, including lay persons.

So, a person can start with the right view with effluents, and later progress to the noble right view.

> "And what is right view? Right view, I tell you, is of two sorts:
> There is right view with effluents, siding with merit, resulting in
> acquisitions [of becoming]; there is right view that is noble, without
> effluents, transcendent, a factor of the path.
>
> "And what is the right view with effluents, siding with merit,
> resulting in acquisitions? 'There is what is given, what is offered,
> what is sacrificed. There are fruits & results of good & bad actions.
> There is this world & the next world. There is mother & father. There
> are spontaneously reborn beings; there are contemplatives & brahmans
> who, faring rightly & practicing rightly, proclaim this world & the
> next after having directly known & realized it for themselves.' This
> is the right view with effluents, siding with merit, resulting in
> acquisitions.
>
> "And what is the right view that is noble, without effluents,
> transcendent, a factor of the path? The discernment, the faculty of
> discernment, the strength of discernment, analysis of qualities as a
> factor for awakening, the path factor of right view in one developing
> the noble path whose mind is noble, whose mind is without effluents,
> who is fully possessed of the noble path. This is the right view that
> is noble, without effluents, transcendent, a factor of the path.
> [MN 117](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.117.than.html)

> “Sir, doesn’t the Buddha live full of compassion for all living
> beings?” “Yes, chief.” “Well, sir, why exactly do you teach some
> people thoroughly and others less thoroughly?”
>
> “Well then, chief, I’ll
> ask you about this in return, and you can answer as you like. What do
> you think? Suppose a farmer has three fields: one’s good, one’s
> average, and one’s poor—bad ground of sand and salt. What do you
> think? When that farmer wants to plant seeds, where would he plant
> them first: the good field, the average one, or the poor one?” “Sir,
> he’d plant them first in the good field, then the average, then he may
> or may not plant seed in the poor field. Why is that? Because at least
> it can be fodder for the cattle.”
>
> “To me, the monks and nuns are like the good field. I teach them the
> Dhamma that’s good in the beginning, good in the middle, and good in
> the end, meaningful and well-phrased. And I reveal a spiritual
> practice that’s entirely full and pure. Why is that? Because they live
> with me as their island, protection, shelter, and refuge.
>
> To me, the
> laymen and laywomen are like the average field. I also teach them the
> Dhamma that’s good in the beginning, good in the middle, and good in
> the end, meaningful and well-phrased. And I reveal a spiritual
> practice that’s entirely full and pure. Why is that? Because they live
> with me as their island, protection, shelter, and refuge.
>
> To me, the
> ascetics, brahmins, and wanderers who follow other paths are like the
> poor field, the bad ground of sand and salt. I also teach them the
> Dhamma that’s good in the beginning, good in the middle, and good in
> the end, meaningful and well-phrased. And I reveal a spiritual
> practice that’s entirely full and pure. Why is that? Hopefully they
> might understand even a single sentence, which would be for their
> lasting welfare and happiness.
> [SN 42.7](https://suttacentral.net/sn42.7/en/sujato)

Comment: Thanks. SN 42.7 is pleasing to a "laymen."

Answer (score 1):

> Do all Dhamma teachings aim us at release?

In a broad sense, yes, they do. In the Sutta pitaka we read about meditation practice, concentration, how to be mindful, let seeing just be seing etc.

In the Vinaya pitaka we learn about all the rules and precepts, the ethics so to say, and the ethics is what gives rise to calm and concentration.

The concentration lets us realize and understand the mind which is taught in the Abhidhamma pitaka, e.g. the 89 minds, the 52 cetasikas etc. Wisdom is what sets the mind free and issues liberation from the rounds of suffering.

Comment: Thanks. Nice pic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, without exception, when spoken to in regard of the world, equal and lower. Yet, no, in regard of striving for higher and release, the Gems, the practice, good attitudes for all that. And one would be required to leave first, to understand it's clearance, otherwise on would just use any reference to maintain his house, stand.

Comment: Not sure that I understand. Possibly lost in translation. Reference?

Comment: @stick-in-hand He is advising you to renounce the world and become a monk or nun, and not use the teachings to remain a householder.

Comment: @stick-in-hand And perhaps the beginning is saying, "Yes, 'disenchantment' towards the (equal and lower) world; but, not 'disenchantment' towards what's higher, i.e. Right Effort, the Three Jewels, the Noble Path, etc." and then "But you would need to leave (home) first" e.g. go a monastery.

Comment: @ruben2020 Thanks, you seem certain. In that case, he's misunderstood the question when he says "Yet, no..." I never said disenchantment with anything in particular. I'm talking about disenchantment as a cause. It's very clear in the question. Or, he's using the forum to voice an irrelevant personal opinion, on how other people should live. Either way, this answer should disappear, or be downvoted, so that nobody misunderstands it to have any merit.

Comment: One not leaving his stand, not giving up, e.g. no Saddha, isn't fit to be taught, as he pulls all just into his house of identification. Total Disenchantment (vipassana) is effect of the right path, comes right before release.